# How to set custom syntax coloring for PowerShell 5.0?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I recently upgraded a Windows 8.1 computer I had to Windows 10, which comes with PowerShell 5.0 by default. I noticed that [PowerShell now has syntax coloring](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857339.aspx#BKMK_newcore) for keywords, cmdlets, strings, etc.:

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way to set a custom color scheme? For example, comments are currently green and I'd like to make them gray. Is this possible?

Comment: Also note, this feature is available in older powershells with the installation of the `PSReadline` module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your second question, the following line will change the comment text to a Gray color:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor Gray
```

You probably will want to execute this when PowerShell is launched, if so, then add this to your Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file.

And to answer your first question for a color scheme, you can add several lines changing the TokenKind value to any of the following members from TokenClassification enum: None, Comment, Keyword, String, Operator, Variable, Command, Parameter, Type, Number and Member.  Also change the -ForgroundColor and -BackgroundColor values with any members of ConsoleColor.

There are color scheme projects available such as [posh-monokai](https://github.com/ntwb/posh-monokai).